# Remove hours:minutes:seconds from System.DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to insert just `year : month : day` for a specific column in a database table row, but my variable is of `DateTime` Type.

To remove `milliseconds` I just used following code:

```
DateTime createdate = System.DateTime.Now;
createdate = createdate.AddTicks(-(createdate.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond));
```

How to remove hours, minutes, seconds from this?

Comment: What database and what is the datatype of the column that you want to set?

Comment: By the way, you mean `year : month : day` instead of `year : month : date`, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.Date` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date) which set's the time part to midnight.

```
DateTime justDate = createdate.Date;
```

or you can use [`DateTime.Today`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today) which generates the same result for `DateTime.Now.Date` value.

```
DateTime justDate = DateTime.Today;
```

If you use SQL Server, [`date` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) is mapped with `DateTime` on CLR side which you can safely insert *that* value.

Comment: It's also worth adding that, if it is the _current date_ you want, then you can use `DateTime.Today`, which is conceptually the same as `DateTime.Now.Date`

Comment: @christophano Yeap, added that as well. Thanks.

Comment: Not that performance is an issue here, but DateTime.Today is conceivably more performant than DateTime.Now.Date, but even if it weren't, preferring abstraction is always best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) property on your `createdate` variable to return just the date component without the time component.

```
DateTime createdate = System.DateTime.Now;
createdate = createdate.AddTicks(-(createdate.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond));
var dateOnly = createdate.Date;
```

Note you will still have the time in the object, set to `00:00:00`